Problem with deploying finetuned gemma in AWS sagemaker as an endpoint

I have finetuned a gemma 7b LLM from HuggingFace using Lora and stored the model as a compressed  .tar.gz file.
I have finetuned locally in sagemaker.



this is my .tar.gz  file structure of finetuned model :

finetuned_gemma/model-00004-of-00004.safetensors
finetuned_gemma/tokenizer_config.json
finetuned_gemma/model.safetensors.index.json
finetuned_gemma/config.json
finetuned_gemma/model-00002-of-00004.safetensors
finetuned_gemma/generation_config.json
finetuned_gemma/special_tokens_map.json
finetuned_gemma/model-00001-of-00004.safetensors
finetuned_gemma/tokenizer.json
finetuned_gemma/code/
finetuned_gemma/code/requirements.txt
finetuned_gemma/code/.ipynb_checkpoints/
finetuned_gemma/code/.ipynb_checkpoints/requirements-checkpoint.txt
finetuned_gemma/code/inference.py
finetuned_gemma/model-00003-of-00004.safetensors

The finetuned model is also stored in aws s3.
How do I now deploy the model as a sagemaker endpoint?
By the way I have used transformers version 4.38.0 as it is the minimum requirement for gemma tokenizer.
I want to know how to deploy it along with the image Uri.
Please help
I tried using sagemaker.huggingfacemodel and then tried deploying it but I'm facing lots of difficulties.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You could use the SageMaker Large Model Inference (LMI) container supports gemma models.
https://docs.djl.ai/docs/serving/serving/docs/lmi/deployment_guide/deploying-your-endpoint.html#configuration---servingproperties
